# Ошибка CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path

Tags: python, mysql, django

При выполнении команды python manage.py dbshell выдается ошибка указанная в заголовке, при этом миграции проходят, таблицы создаются. Понятно, что ругается на неверный путь, но где его поменять я не нашел. Проект стоит на виртуальном окружении, возможно в этом проблема.

Comment: При запуске CLI без указания пути к исполняемому файлу из произвольного текущего каталога - он запускается?

Comment: Нет, не запускается.

Comment: Ну так добавьте путь к модулю в системный PATH...